# How to obtain a backend transport type/configuration in MPI (openMPI application)?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

So I having an access to submit jobs to a small cluster, how to obtain inside an MPI app what type of backend MPI is running on (infiniband, ethernet, etc)?

Comment: Why do you care? You just send and receive, MPI handles the rest. That is what MPI is for.

Comment: I have a 10G ethernet and Mellanox Technologies MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3] thus I wonder which one is used?

Comment: You must at least tell us which MPI implementation you use. ry to find the most details you know. Did you look into the manual of your MPI?

Comment: the title states 'openMPI'. For OpenMPI you can figure out what is used by enabling some debug output for the MCA/BTL in `mpirun`. You might have to dig deep into the OpenMPI documentation to find out what those parameters are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open MPI ranks the network interconnects it finds on each host and selects the fastest one that allows communication with the other nodes. InfiniBand always wins over Ethernet unless one fiddles with the BTL component priorities (one usually doesn't).

To see the components being selected, set the verbosity level of the BTL framework to at least 5:

```
$ mpiexec --mca btl_base_verbose 5 -np 2 ./a.out 
[host:08691] mca: bml: Using self btl to [[56717,1],1] on node host
[host:08690] mca: bml: Using self btl to [[56717,1],0] on node host
[host:08691] mca: bml: Using vader btl to [[56717,1],0] on node host
[host:08690] mca: bml: Using vader btl to [[56717,1],1] on node host
```

What you see here is that modules from two BTL components were instantiated:

- `self`, which Open MPI uses to communicate within the same process;
- `vader`, previously known as `sm`, which implements message passing via shared-memory for processes on the same node.

If TCP/IP over the 10G Ethernet or IPoIB is used, you'll see the `tcp` BTL being selected. Otherwise, the output depends on the Open MPI version you have. With the older versions, Mellanox InfiniBand HCAs are driven natively by the `openib` BTL component. With the newer versions, the `mx` MTL takes over and you might need to increase the verbosity of the MTL framework instead by setting `mtl_base_verbose` to 5.